# Dialogflow fulfillment - How to add multiple agent.add() responses?

Tags: flutter, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have a list of firestore snapshot that I want to be as responses to an intent. I declare it into "res" varible and pass it into agent.add but it doesn't work. The "res" variable doesn't print anything.

**Here is my code:**

```
async function handlerReadFromDB(agent) {
let uId = agent.originalRequest.payload.uId;
console.log(uId);
const dataRef = db.collection('users').doc(`${uId}`).collection('medic_reminder');
const snapshot = await dataRef.get();
var med={};
var medObj = [];
var medRef={};
snapshot.forEach(doc => {
  med=doc.data();
  medObj.push({data: med});
});
var i;
var str="You need to take ";
for( i in medObj){
 str = str +`${medObj[i].data.medName} at ${medObj[i].data.hour}:${medObj[i].data.min},`;
  i++;
}
console.log(str);
return agent.add(`Yes, `+str);
  }
```

Comment: Do you get any error when testing the agent ? If not does it return something?

Comment: The function crash

Comment: Can you see any error message in the logs ?

Comment: I have updated my code and there is no error in console. But I still did not receive response in my app.

Comment: Have you followed [these](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/tutorials/build-an-agent/create-fulfillment-using-webhook) instructions to create your webhook ?